# SQL Server select query lock insert. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, isolation-level

I have two SQL select queries executed on SQL Server 2008 R2 without explicit transactions

Query 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Field1 = 'XXX' AND Field2 = 'YYY'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Field1 = N'XXX' AND Field2 = N'YYY'
```

"Query 2" is faster than "Query 1", but while "Query 2" is running I can't write (`INSERT`) new records on "MyTable"..."MyTable" seems locked. Instead, while "Query 1" is running I can add new records quietly.

Note: "MyTable" has a clustered composite key (two columns) and other INDEXES.

Can you explain why this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your default isolation-level? `DBCC useroptions;`

Comment: It's "Read Committed"

Comment: Does query 1 and query 2 return the same amount of rows?

Comment: Yes...are the same query, change only the way of parameters assignment.

Comment: @Luca Petrini, did you find an explaination?

Comment: @RuslanK. I'm investigating...the cause is the presence of indexes. If I delete them I no longer have the problem, but I have a deterioration in performance. I also tested the solution posted by Pouria Sharif, but still I did not get results.

Comment: Have you tried to analyze the locks using `sp_lock2`?

Comment: At the end, I worked around the problem by reading data by one "Read Uncommitted" transaction (in my case should not be a problem). Anyway, the problem occurred with the presence of one specific index (note: the table has more than 10 million records); removing that index changes the execution plan and the insert is not blocked (but the query appeared much slower).

Answer (score 1):

Use the ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS clause of ALTER/CREATE INDEX:

```
ALTER INDEX indexname ON tablename SET (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF);
```

Comment: I tested your solution but without any result...anyhow the cause is the presence of indexes...if I delete them I no longer have the problem, but I have a deterioration in performance. I'm investigating.